React Native App crashes randomly on both Android and iOS with no logs in Console, Sentry and Firebase Crashlytics
I am experiencing random crashes in my React Native application that I am unable to reproduce consistently. I have integrated both Sentry and Firebase Crashlytics, but neither is capturing these crashes. The issue occurs across multiple devices. Its rate is higher in iOS compared to android. But overall the reproduction rate of this issue is low and there are no steps. Our application consist of following features.

Used Redux Toolkit  for both client and server state management
Text Message functionality which is implemented using SocketIO
Audio/Video Calls using @zoom/react-native-videosdk and react-native-agora
Voice Note, Image and Documents via messages
Integration of Payment Gateway using hyperpay(Apple Pay, Visa, Master and Mada) and Tabby.
Caches user profile picture for faster images loading using react-native-blob-util

When the app crashed on debug I got a pop up from XCode regarding crash whose screenshots are listed below





Added react-native-exception-handler, but was not able to capture any issues with it. though I tried crashing it manually in debug mode which worked perfectly fine.

We cache images in our application using react-native-blob-util. I tried disabling image cache logic to see whether this library was causing any issues.

Integrated both Sentry and Firebase Crashlytics to see of issue is logged there. But no issue regarding these random crashes is reported there.

Tried removing Sentry(configuration and implementation) to see whether if sentry was causing any issues.

Tried making http calls instead of https call to check if NSAllowsArbitraryLoads(which is set to false in our application) was causing any issues

Monitored RAM usage from Developer Menu > Perf Monitor in which the maximum RAM used by our application on full load went up to 820mbs. We tried using the app on full load by frequently calling multiple APIs, randomly switching between screens and initiating Audio Video Calls along with messaging. Here is the package.json


{
  "name": "exampleApp",
  "version": "4.8.22",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:android:bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd ..",
    "build:android:release": "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease && cd ..",
    "clean:android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../",
    "cra": "yarn clean:android && yarn run:android",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged --config lint-staged.js",
    "pod:install": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
    "pod:remove": "cd ios && pod deintegrate && cd ..",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prettier": "prettier src -check",
    "run:android": "react-native run-android",
    "run:ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer": "^3.0.7",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.14.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^20.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^20.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@zoom/react-native-videosdk": "^1.11.0",
    "card-validator": "^9.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "html-parse-stringify": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.45",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "query-string": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",
    "react-native": "0.74.6",
    "react-native-agora": "^4.3.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "^6.14.3",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-autolink": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.11",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.1304.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.2",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.3.5",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.7",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.12.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-floating-label-input": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.2.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.15.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-scroll-picker-wheel": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-share": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
    "react-native-sms-retriever": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "tabby-react-native-sdk": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.88",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.88",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.88",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.88",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-i18n": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-native-version-check": "^3.4.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.18.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.18.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tsc-files": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}


From the crash log it looks like you are running your simulator in Rosseta on M2 Mac. Does this crash happen also on real devices/without Rosseta?
It's a long shot, but maybe it can help.

@KrystofWoldrich its also happening on real devices in both debug and release builds

you can try test it with android studio logcat maybe you can catch the fatal error and solve it
